# Videojs full screen don't work

Tags: jquery, css, video, html5-video, video.js

I have to public a drupal site but i cannot fix the last bug.

If you go in
www(dot)actomedia(dot)com/dev/actomedia/
and click on the s-up icon in the menu you will see a video. If you play start and click the full screen icon the overlay disappear with the video.

Throught (chrome) console you can search
jQuery('#video1')
and the right click on the console object and 'Reveal the elements panel', then if you click on element and select 'Scroll into view' you can see the video is invisible and a black box cover all the screen.

How can I fix that problem? 
I'm becoming crazy to fix that.

Comment: I don't see any videos on that page?

Comment: You have to enter on that page and click on the last entry of the menu: the s-up icon. An overlay will appear with the video inside.